# Lazy Loading Rows to (MUI) DataGridPro (example help)

Tags: material-ui, lazy-loading

Regarding example: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-updates/#lazy-loading

Im confused on where the example data ends and where the necessary params begin. Essentially, what in this can I comment out/remove/replace to hook my database up?

Example data is being loaded into the gird; I assume through:
`import { createFakeServer, loadServerRows } from '@mui/x-data-grid-generator';`
Is this only for the example or also needed for the LazyLoading to work? In other words, is a "fake server" being created that MUI is referencing or...?

I've written code to query my database and return rows, I have it setup with variables to accept a `startAt` and `limit` which I can link with the MUI datagrid, Im just not sure where to.

For example in the below, are `filterModel`, `sortModel`, `columnsWithDefaultColDef`, etc. needed? is this just for querying example data? I see that "dataServerSide" at the bottom, so am I leaving everything and only updating dataServerSide elsewhere or?

```
const fetchRow = React.useCallback(
    async (params) => {
      const serverRows = await loadServerRows(
        dataServerSide,
        {
          filterModel: params.filterModel,
          sortModel: params.sortModel,
        },
        {
          minDelay: 300,
          maxDelay: 800,
          useCursorPagination: false,
        },
        columnsWithDefaultColDef,
      );

      return {
        slice: serverRows.returnedRows.slice(
          params.firstRowToRender,
          params.lastRowToRender,
        ),
        total: serverRows.returnedRows.length,
      };
    },
    [dataServerSide],
  );
```

Hope someone can help

I've tried creating external state management to inject/update rows but it doesn't use the lazy loading functionality, its jerry rigged to fire at `onRowsScrollEnd`. Id like to use the lazyLoading feature, despite it being experiential.